# Regex to match em in css file

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write a method in c# to convert PX to EM and viceversa in a css file.

To accomplish that i want to use regex to match the value (eg 12em) and convert it into px.

So far i have the following expression

```
(.*)^([0-9,-\.]+)(px)(.*)
```

this matches

```
border: solid 3em gray;  
margin: 1.2em 2em 3em 4em;    
margin: 1em  2em     3em    4em ;
```

but not

```
 width:50.1em; 
 width: 50.1em;
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a much simpler needle, like this one.

```
([\d.])+em
```

There are probably potential cases where it wouldn't work, but they are few and far between, e.g.

```
background-image: url('http://site.tld/something/5em/not/likely/');
```

If you need prevention of something like that, get a CSS parser.

[demo](http://rubular.com/r/2R5dbTWxAe)

Answer (score 0):

Try `(.+):(.*)^([0-9,-\.]+)(px)(.*)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe: `([0-9,-\.]+)\s*(em)`? See [the example](http://rubular.com/r/yBrmVPGUyS).

Answer (score 0):

The pattern that worked for me is

```
(.*?:?)([0-9,-\.]+)\s*(em)(.*)
```

Thanks alextercete for pointing to that Regular Expression Helper.